# Fast IMAP client with Idle, pipelining, triggered both-way sync

Tags: linux, email-client, imap

What is the best IMAP email synchronizer client that runs on Linux?

I define *best* as follows:

- Fastest run time to sync an IMAP mailbox down to my local maildir.
- Must support IMAP Idle.
- Must support pipelining.
- Must synchronize both ways in a triggered manner, not in periodic refresh manner. For example, if I read an email locally, I want this IMAP client to update my email server immediately *upon* reading the email, such that the email copy in the server is marked as *read*. This is different than the alternative approach of having the email client *periodically* sync.

Comment: If such a thing exists, I'd love to know! I've been unable to find anything better than isync/mbsync and have just started trying to hack something together in python